# Very large variation of the time elapsed when a small write to Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, optimization, database-connection, libpqxx

I'm a freshman with Postgresql, so any hints or tips are appreciated.

My program is very small. It receives data from socket, and then insert them into a table that has no index/foreign key/constrain/Text Field. In the fact, it has a few of numeric fields only.

My data from network is coming continuously at a rate about 100 to 1000 records per seconds. My Postgresql is not optimized at all, and every thing of it is running at the default values.

The trouble is
**The time consumption of every db-insert varys in a very wide range.** The maximum time of a single insert might be 10s, and the minimum one might be 100us, while the average one is about 900us.

Even though I can increase the length of buffer, to avoid the buffer be exhausted when we wait for a too long insert to finish, I think this is NOT the correct solution, because regardless how long the buffer length is, we might encounter a more slower insert. 
I guesss **it is abnormal in the world of Postgresql(10s for writing a tiny plain table)**, but I have no idea to solve it, so I ask it here to hope someone point out my mistake or some optimizing methods.

env: Centos 7.5 64bit, Postgresql 10, gcc 8.2.0 and latest pqxx lib.

This is my pg_hba.conf

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust

# IPv4 incoming connections:
host    all             all             all                     password

# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident

# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 ident
```

and the postgresql.conf

```
listen_addresses = '*'          # what IP address(es) to listen on;
max_connections = 100           # (change requires restart)
shared_buffers = 128MB          # min 128kB
dynamic_shared_memory_type = posix  # the default is the first option
log_destination = 'stderr'      # Valid values are combinations of
logging_collector = on          # Enable capturing of stderr and csvlog
log_directory = 'log'           # directory where log files are written,
log_filename = 'postgresql-%a.log'  # log file name pattern,
log_truncate_on_rotation = on       # If on, an existing log file with the
log_rotation_age = 1d           # Automatic rotation of logfiles will
log_rotation_size = 0           # Automatic rotation of logfiles will
log_line_prefix = '%m [%p] '        # special values:
log_timezone = 'PRC'
datestyle = 'iso, ymd'
timezone = 'PRC'
lc_messages = 'zh_CN.UTF-8'         # locale for system error message
lc_monetary = 'zh_CN.UTF-8'         # locale for monetary formatting
lc_numeric = 'zh_CN.UTF-8'          # locale for number formatting
lc_time = 'zh_CN.UTF-8'             # locale for time formatting
default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.simple'
```

Sorry for my English, I'm a Chinese. I appreciate any patience to read my poor English.
Thanks!

Comment: show your database configurations

Comment: thanks for your reply. The configs have been added.

Comment: How often do you commit? Are there any concurrent transactions that may cause a lock? Try to attach to the backend with `strace` and see where the time is spent.

Comment: Sorry for too later, because I'm busy these days.

My program commits a record about every 1us -- 1ms.
No transaction is needed, because there is only one tiny table to be insert(not update).
This table has no index/pk/fk/constrain.